# Can I open a text file in one script, then write to that file in a child script?

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

This is a little bit of a strange question, but I have a bunch of automation scripts (using Sikuli/Jython), that i want to run from a parent script for regression purposes.  Now I also have a method of capturing exceptions that I want to log to a text file.  SO here's how it currently works:

```
Master Script --> specific test script
              --> specific test script
              --> etc (how ever many scripts there are)
```

I was talking to a friend of mine, and he recommended that each script handles its own errors, and that the parent script just opens a file, makes the file location a global variable, and the child scripts just append to that file.

Basically, do I need to do anything special in python to make this possible? or is the master script basically just "touching" a file that other scripts can use.

Here is an example of the "parent script"  (this does not have any code to handle errors in it, nor does it open a file, just executes the scripts)

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("c:\directory\to\the\scripts"):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".py")]:
        directory.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
for entry in directory:
    execfile(entry)
```

Comment: do you need to sync between the two scripts, otherwise why don't you write to a copy of that file then update when the file handle is closed elsewhere?

Comment: Its not very important to sync between the scripts, no.  I just want something that is flexible, since there could be multiple tiers of parent scripts (e.g. parent scripts that run parent scripts that then run similar test scripts).  The idea is that the logfiles would be named <timestamp>_uiTest.log (or something like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I also have a method of capturing exceptions that I want to log to a text file.

Use `logging`.  http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

The problem has already been solved by them.  No work for you.